# Get the difference between one sub-Array or multiple sub-Arrays in a multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I have following multidimensional Array and I want to get the difference, if there is just one sub Array or multiple in that array.

For Example:

- In Array [1] there is just one sub Array [example]
- In Array [2] there are two sub Arrays [example]

```html
[content] => Array
        (
            [...]
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [example] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => GET THIS
                            [attr] => Array
                                (
                                  [...]
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [example] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GET THIS
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                           [...]
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GET THIS
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                           [...]
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
```

Now to get the [value] from the first Array I would try:

```
foreach ($content as $example) {
    echo($content['example']['value']);
}
```

And to get each [value] from the second Array I would try:

```
foreach ($content as $example) {
    foreach ($example as $values) {
        echo($value['value']);
    }
}
```

So far so good but how do I decide which function to run? Am I missing something?
Is there an if-statement which can help me there?

Something like:

```
if(multiple sub-arrays){
    // do first code example
} else {
    // do second code example
}
```

I simply want a method to get all values called [value] out of the array.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I read your question twice and still can't quite get what is the problem you're trying to solve. Can you make an example of the final result you are expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to change function which generates your `content` array so as it **always** generates sub arrays in a format like:

```
[content] => Array
        (
            [...]
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [example] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GET THIS
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [...]
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [example] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GET THIS
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                           [...]
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GET THIS
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                           [...]
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
```

But if you don't have such option - then use a simple check:

```
foreach ($content as $item) {
    // here check if your `$item` has an `value` subkey under `example` key
    if (array_key_exists('value', $item['example'])) {
         echo($item['example']['value']);
    } else {
         foreach ($item['example'] as $values) {
             echo ($values['value']);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I were not able to change my constructor function. So this is the solution I searched for :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your final dimension allways as a 'value' node:

```
function arrayIterate($array){
    foreach ($content as $example) {
        if(!isset($example['value'])){
            arrayIterate($example);
        }else{
            echo($example['value']);
        }
    }
}
```